# what components need for clustering two windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cluster, failover, windows-cluster

what are the basic requirement for clustering in windows 2008 server?

1.i mean which exact 2008 server licence
2. how can i connect two server what component i need for that?
3. what is minimum hardware require for server?
3. any other licenses or components need for this project?

a

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you will need two servers with Server 2008 Standard/Enterprise/Datacenter licenses, as well as some type of shared storage, such as a iSCSI/Fibre Channel SAN or Direct Attached RAID array.  The specific hardware needed depends on your budget, preference, and intended use.  If you can elaborate on these, I'm sure that I (or someone else) would be able to suggest solutions for you.

Note that there are very few options for free/low cost shared storage and the ones that are out there are not really suitable for business production use.